# Saving PNG file created by Google Chart API

Tags: php, google-api, imagecreatefrompng

Created a QR code using Google API ( Yes I know its deprecated )
However I can't seem to save the image generated.
If I click the image and try and save it only saves a PHP file

Any ideas ??

Here is the code

```
$data = isset($_GET['data']) ? $_GET['data'] : 'FGS Ingredients';
$size = isset($_GET['size']) ? $_GET['size'] : '300x300';
$logo = 'fgsqrcodelogo.png';
header('Content-type: image/png');
// Get QR Code image from Google Chart API
// http://code.google.com/apis/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes.html
$QR = imagecreatefrompng('https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chld=H|1&chs='.$size.'&chl='.urlencode($data));
if($logo !== FALSE){
    $logo = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($logo));
    $QR_width = imagesx($QR);
    $QR_height = imagesy($QR);

    $logo_width = imagesx($logo);
    $logo_height = imagesy($logo);

    // Scale logo to fit in the QR Code
    $logo_qr_width = $QR_width/3;
    $scale = $logo_width/$logo_qr_width;
    $logo_qr_height = $logo_height/$scale;

    imagecopyresampled($QR, $logo, $QR_width/3, $QR_height/3, 0, 0, $logo_qr_width, $logo_qr_height, $logo_width, $logo_height);
}
imagepng($QR);
imagedestroy($QR);
file_put_contents('myfile.png',$QR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it ...
Just added

```
$name = str_replace(' ','-',$data);
$save = "". strtolower($name) .".png";
then changed to imagepng($QR,$save);
```